# Pull out most non overlapping date range

Tags: sql, db2

Sorry, going to start over and try to explain from the start:
I have a small list of dates:

```
date        mark
08-16-2016  1
08-17-2016  1
01-03-2017  1
02-16-2018  1
02-17-2018  1
```

From here I need to find out in a 3 year period if there is 2 continuous years where there are less than 3 marks.  I'm looking over a date range from 2016-08-01 to 2019-08-01.

So I setup the following query:

```
with initData as(
    select date('2016-08-16') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2016-08-17') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2017-01-03') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2018-02-16') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2018-02-17') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select * from(
    select
        a.startDate, a.endDate, coalesce(sum(b.mark),0) as mark
    from(
        select startDate, endDate from(
            select stamp startDate, stamp+1 YEAR endDate
            from(
                select stamp + ym YEAR stamp
                from(
                    select date('2016-08-01') stamp from sysibm.sysdummy1
                    union
                    select stamp from initData
                    union
                    select stamp+1 DAY from initData
                ),
                (
                    select 0 as ym from sysibm.sysdummy1
                    union select 1 as ym from sysibm.sysdummy1
                    union select 2 as ym from sysibm.sysdummy1
                )
            )
        )
        where endDate <= date('2019-08-01')
    ) a
    left outer join(
        select stamp, mark from initData
    ) b
    on b.stamp >= a.startDate
    and b.stamp < a.endDate
    group by a.startDate, a.endDate
    )
where mark < 3
order by startDate, endDate
```

This gives me my list of ranges that I'm looking which have less than 3 marks.  Now I need to find full years that don't over lap with other dates.

```
2016-08-17  2017-08-17  2
2016-08-18  2017-08-18  1
2017-01-03  2018-01-03  1
2017-01-04  2018-01-04  0
2017-08-01  2018-08-01  2
2017-08-16  2018-08-16  2
2017-08-17  2018-08-17  2
2017-08-18  2018-08-18  2
2018-01-03  2019-01-03  2
2018-01-04  2019-01-04  2
2018-02-16  2019-02-16  2
2018-02-17  2019-02-17  1
2018-02-18  2019-02-18  0
2018-08-01  2019-08-01  0
```

I have finally came up with some solution, but it seems a bit slow and seems like there should be a better way to do it:

```
with initData as(
    select date('2016-08-16') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2016-08-17') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2017-01-03') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2018-02-16') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union select date('2018-02-17') stamp, 1 mark from sysibm.sysdummy1
), dateRanges as(
    select startDate, endDate, mark, row_number() over (order by startDate, endDate) rn from(
        select
            a.startDate, a.endDate, coalesce(sum(b.mark),0) as mark
        from(
            select startDate, endDate from(
                select stamp startDate, stamp+1 YEAR endDate
                from(
                    select stamp + ym YEAR stamp
                    from(
                        select date('2016-08-01') stamp from sysibm.sysdummy1
                        union
                        select stamp from initData
                        union
                        select stamp+1 DAY from initData
                    ),
                    (
                        select 0 as ym from sysibm.sysdummy1
                        union select 1 as ym from sysibm.sysdummy1
                        union select 2 as ym from sysibm.sysdummy1
                    )
                )
            )
            where endDate <= date('2019-08-01')
        ) a
        left outer join(
            select stamp, mark from initData
        ) b
        on b.stamp >= a.startDate
        and b.stamp < a.endDate
        group by a.startDate, a.endDate
        )
    where mark < 3
), dateRangeLimit1 as(
    select 
        a.startDate, a.endDate, a.mark, row_number() over (order by a.startDate, a.endDate) rn
    from dateRanges a
    left outer join dateRanges b
    on a.startDate < b.endDate
    and b.rn = 1
    and a.rn != b.rn
    where b.rn is null
)
select a.* from dateRangeLimit1 a
left outer join dateRangeLimit1 b
on a.startDate < b.endDate
and b.rn = 2 and a.rn <> b.rn and a.rn != 1
where b.rn is null
```

This gives me back my expected date ranges that don't over lap with each other:

```
2016-08-17  2017-08-17  2   1
2017-08-17  2018-08-17  2   2
```

I hope this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using.  Is it DB2 or Oracle?  I also don't see how those results are "non-overlapping".

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by "non-overlapping". *MY* definition of "non-overlapping" would be that one date range includes both of the dates of another date range. By that definition none of your first four date ranges would be included in the output of the query because they all "overlap", by my definition, but obviously I'm using a different definition of "overlap" than you are. So, please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include information about how you are defining "non-overlapping". Thanks.

Comment: I hope the above edit makes more sense.  Basically I ended up with a big list of date ranges that have overlaps.  From those i want to pick as many date ranges from that list that don't over lap with each other.  I did include my whole start, because maybe there is just a better way in general to do it and not even have to mess with the overlapping date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your data is quite right, but nonetheless does this help?

```
WITH D(F,T) AS (VALUES
 ('2016-08-09','2017-08-09')
,('2016-08-16','2017-08-16')
,('2016-08-17','2017-08-17')
,('2016-08-18','2017-08-18')
,('2017-08-09','2018-08-09')
,('2017-08-16','2018-08-16')
,('2017-08-17','2018-08-17')
,('2017-08-18','2018-08-18')
,('2018-02-16','2019-02-16')
,('2018-02-17','2019-02-17')
,('2018-02-18','2019-02-18')
,('2018-08-09','2019-08-09')
)
SELECT F,T FROM
(
    SELECT F,T
    , LEAD(F,1) OVER(ORDER BY F ASC) AS NEXT_F
    , LAG( T,1) OVER(ORDER BY F ASC) AS PREV_T
    FROM   D
)
WHERE T >= NEXT_F
OR    F <= PREV_T
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me back what was needed, thank you though.

Comment: OK. Well maybe it at least showed you that you don't need to use UNION of SELECTs from SYSDUMMY1 to generate multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

`from dual` apparently points to ORACLE.

Find the longest path of non-overlapping (end = start considered non-overlapping) intervals

```
select level, sys_connect_by_path (startDate || ' .. ' || endDate, '/') path
from blah a
connect by (prior startDate < startDate) and not(prior startDate < endDate and startDate < prior endDate)
order by level desc
-- fetch is 12c+ feature
fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Using sample data returns

```
3   /09-AUG-16 .. 09-AUG-17/09-AUG-17 .. 09-AUG-18/09-AUG-18 .. 09-AUG-19
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5d028ee67070599e32f8c3953251d5e)

Comment: This is an interesting query and does pull the required ranges.  I was hoping to have a list of startDate, endDates in rows still though.  I also don't know how to replicate this to db2.  Unfortunately I'm better with oracle, than db2, so I gave my example in it.